# get folder with newest date name

Tags: linux, bash, date, directory

I have this folders:

```
2014-09-01-00:00:01
2014-09-01-01:00:01
2014-09-01-02:00:01
2014-09-01-03:00:01
2014-09-01-04:00:01
```

(There are many more folders)

I write this names to an array. (`folders=("2014-09-01-00:00:01" "2014-09-01-01:00:01"...)`)

How can I get the folder with the newest date? (Not based on the creation/modified date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` is the first thing to think about, but [parsing ls is evil](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Hence, I would use `find` for this:

```
find /your/path -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort -rn
```

It looks for all the directories in `/your/path` (not sub-directories) and sorts them numerically.

The first one will be the newer. Adding `| head -1` we get just that one.

Comment: Oh :/ That was easy. I thought it is more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Given the convenient date/time format you're using, you can simply sort lexicographically, using `sort`:

```
ls -d PARENT_DIR/*/ | sort | tail -1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below command

```
 ll -rt | tail -n 1
```

Actually it will give you the latest file or directory in your parent directory.

But as you added in your question that your parent directory contains only directories. You can simply use above command.

Answer (score 0):

bash [filename pattern expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) gives you alphabetically sorted results, so:

```
folders=(*/)
echo "${folders[-1]}"
```